# do-release-upgrade requests updates when there are none

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, package-management, upgrade

I am upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04. I have updated 18.04. When I run:

```
$ sudo apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
xscreensaver-data-extra/bionic 5.36-1ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.34-2ubuntu1]
xscreensaver-data-extra/now 5.34-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.36-1ubuntu1]
```

If I then run sudo update-manager I get a window that says:The software on this computer is up to date. However, Ubuntu 20.04 is now available(you have 18.04). When I click the Upgrade window I get: Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading. What do I need to do to complete the upgrade process?

Comment: Run `sudo apt update;sudo apt upgrade` and resolve any errors.

Comment: I'd suggest `sudo apt full-upgrade` & always check you didn't put holds on any packages (`apt-mark showhold`), and read your `sudo apt update` lines to ensure you're not missing any lines (ie. later packages aren't being detected because of flaws in your sources; and what 3rd party sources are there as they can cause problems)

Comment: $ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  xscreensaver-data-extra
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Comment: How do I get past this problem? $ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  xscreensaver-data-extra
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Is   xscreensaver-data-extra my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Take this link steps on official Ubuntu blog:
[How to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS today](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today)

before starting the update, run this commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

if didn't work, try these:

```
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt upgrade -y
```